# x86 labels and LEA in GDB

Tags: memory, assembly, gdb, x86, nasm

I"m learning to code in x86 assembly (32-bit at the moment) and I'm struggling to understand the memory model completely.  Particularly confusing is the semantics for labels, and the LEA instruction, and the layout of the executable.  I wrote this sample program so i could inspect it running in gdb.

```
; mem.s
SECTION .data
    msg: db "labeled string\n"
    db "unlabeled-string\n"
    nls: db 10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10
SECTION .text
global  _start
_start:
    ; inspect msg label, LEA instruction
    mov eax, msg
    mov eax, &msg
    mov eax, [msg]
    ; lea eax, msg (invalid instruction)
    lea eax, &msg
    lea eax, [msg]

    ; populate array in BSS section
    mov [arr], DWORD 1
    mov [arr+4], DWORD 2
    mov [arr+8], DWORD 3
    mov [arr+12], DWORD 4

    ; trying to print the unlabeled string
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    lea ecx, [msg+15]
    int 80H

    mov eax, 1      ; exit syscall
    mov ebx, 0      ; return value
    int 80H
SECTION .bss
    arr: resw 16
```

I've assembled and linked with:

```
nasm -f elf -g -F stabs mem.s
ld -m elf_i386 -o mem mem.o
```

GDB session:

```
(gdb) disas *_start
Dump of assembler code for function _start:
   0x08048080 <+0>: mov    $0x80490e4,%eax
   0x08048085 <+5>: mov    0x80490e4,%eax
   0x0804808a <+10>:    mov    0x80490e4,%eax
   0x0804808f <+15>:    lea    0x80490e4,%eax
   0x08048095 <+21>:    lea    0x80490e4,%eax
   0x0804809b <+27>:    movl   $0x1,0x8049110
   0x080480a5 <+37>:    movl   $0x2,0x8049114
   0x080480af <+47>:    movl   $0x3,0x8049118
   0x080480b9 <+57>:    movl   $0x4,0x804911c
   0x080480c3 <+67>:    mov    $0x4,%eax
   0x080480c8 <+72>:    mov    $0x1,%ebx
   0x080480cd <+77>:    lea    0x80490f3,%ecx
   0x080480d3 <+83>:    int    $0x80
   0x080480d5 <+85>:    mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x080480da <+90>:    mov    $0x0,%ebx
   0x080480df <+95>:    int    $0x80
```

inspecting "msg" value:

```
(gdb) b _start
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8048080
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/jh/workspace/x86/mem_addr/mem
(gdb) p msg
# what does this value represent?
$1 = 1700946284
(gdb) p &msg
$2 = (<data variable, no debug info> *) 0x80490e4
# this is the address where "labeled string" is stored
(gdb) p *0x80490e4
# same value as above (eg: p msg)
$3 = 1700946284
(gdb) p *msg
Cannot access memory at address 0x6562616c
# NOTE: 0x6562616c is ASCII values of 'e','b','a','l'
# the first 4 bytes from msg: db "labeled string"... little-endian
(gdb) x msg
0x6562616c: Cannot access memory at address 0x6562616c
(gdb) x &msg
0x80490e4 <msg>:    0x6562616c
(gdb) x *msg
Cannot access memory at address 0x6562616c
```

Stepping through one instruction at a time:

```
(gdb) p $eax
$4 = 0
(gdb) stepi
0x08048085 in _start ()
(gdb) p $eax
$5 = 134516964
0x0804808a in _start ()
(gdb) p $eax
$6 = 1700946284
(gdb) stepi
0x0804808f in _start ()
(gdb) p $eax
$7 = 1700946284
(gdb) stepi
0x08048095 in _start ()
(gdb) p $eax
$8 = 134516964
```

The array was populated with the values 1,2,3,4 as expected:

```
# before program execution:
(gdb) x/16w &arr
0x8049104 <arr>:    0   0   0   0
0x8049114:  0   0   0   0
0x8049124:  0   0   0   0
0x8049134:  0   0   0   0
# after program execution
(gdb) x/16w &arr
0x8049104 <arr>:    1   2   3   4
0x8049114:  0   0   0   0
0x8049124:  0   0   0   0
0x8049134:  0   0   0   0
```

I don't understand why printing a label in gdb results in those two values.  Also, how can I print the unlabeled string.
Thanks in advance

Comment: i was able to print out the unlabeled string like this:
`(gdb) p (char*) (&msg)+16`
`$1 = 0x80490f4 "unlabeled-string\\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" <Address 0x804910e out of bounds>`

Comment: the other value is the address of msg in decimal
`(gdb) p/d &msg` 
`$10 = 134516964`

Comment: NOTE: sys_write needs the length of the string at edx
so: `mov edx, 17` before `int 80H`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its somewhat confusing because gdb doesn't understand the concept of labels, really -- its designed to debug a program written in higher-level language (C or C++, generally) and compiled by a compiler.  So it tries to map what it sees in the binary to high-level language concepts -- variables and types -- based on its best guess as to what is going on (in the absence of debug info from the compiler that tells it what is going on).

**what nasm does**

To the assembler, a label is value that hasn't been set yet -- it actually gets its final value when the linker runs.  Generally, labels are used to refer to addresses in sections of memory -- the actual address will get defined when the linker lays out the final executable image.  The assembler generates relocation records so that uses of the label can be set properly by the linker.

So when the assembler sees

```
mov eax, msg
```

it knows that `msg` is a label corresponding to an address in the data segment, so it generates an instruction to load that address into eax.  When it sees

```
mov eax, [msg]
```

it generates an instruction to load 32-bits (the size of register eax) from memory at address of `msg`.  In both cases, there will be a relocation generated so that the linker can plug in the final address `msg` ends up with.

(aside -- I have no idea what `&` means to nasm -- it doesn't appear anywhere in the documentation I can see, so I'm suprised it doesn't give an error.  But it looks like it treats it as an alias for `[]`)

Now LEA is a funny instruction -- it has basically the same format as a move from memory, but instead of reading memory, it stores the address it would have read from into the destination register.  So

```
lea eax, msg
```

makes no sense -- the source is the label (address) `msg`, which is a (link time) constant and is not in memory anywhere.

```
lea eax, [msg]
```

works, as the source is in memory, so it sticks the address of the source into eax.  This is the same effect as `mov eax, msg`.  Most commonly, you only see `lea` used with more complex addressing modes, so that you can leverage the x86 AGU to do useful work other than just computing addresses.  Eg:

```
lea eax, [ebx+4*ecx+32]
```

which does a shift and two adds in the AGU and puts the result into eax rather than loading from that address.

**what gdb does**

In gdb, when you type `p <expression>` it tries to evaluate `<expression>` to the best of its understanding of what the C/C++ compiler means for that expression.  So when you say

```
(gdb) p msg
```

it looks at `msg` and says "that looks like a variable, so lets get the current value of that variable and print that".  Now it knows that compilers like to put global variables into the .data segment, and that they create symbols for those variables with the same name as the varible.  Since it sees `msg` in the symbol table as a symbol in the `.data` segment, it assumes that is what is going on, and fetches the memory at that symbol and prints it.  Now it has no idea what TYPE that variable is (no debug info), so it guesses that it is a 32-bit int and prints it as that.

So the output

```
$1 = 1700946284
```

is the first 4 bytes of msg, treated as an integer.

For `p &msg` it understands you want to take the address of the variable `msg`, so it give the address from the symbol directly.   When printing addresses, gdb prints the type information it has about those addresses, thus the "data variable, no debug info" that comes out with it.

If you want, you can use a cast to specify the type of something to gdb, and it will use that type instead of what it has guessed:

```
(gdb) p (char)msg
$6 = 108 'l'
(gdb) p (char [10])msg
$7 = "labeled st"
(gdb) p (char *)&msg
$8 = 0x80490e4 "labeled string\\nunlabeled-string\\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" <Address 0x804910e out of bounds>
```

Note in the latter case here, there's no NUL terminator on the string, so it prints out the entire data segment...

---

To print the unlabelled string with sys_write, you need to figure out the address
and length of string, which you almost have.  For completeness you should also check the return value:

```
    mov ebx, 1           ; fd 1 (stdout)
    lea ecx, [msg+15]    ; address
    mov edx, 17          ; length
write_more:
    mov eax, 4           ; sys_write
    int 80H              ; write(1, &msg[15], 17)
    test eax, eax        ; check for error
    js error             ; error, eax = -ERRNO
    add ecx, eax
    sub edx, eax
    jg write_more        ; only part of the string was written
```

Comment: I was able to get the other value with this:
`(gdb) p (int[]) &msg`
`$1 = {134516964}`

Comment: is there a way to print the unlabeled string with sys_write system call?

Answer (score 4):

Chris Dodd sez...

---

### (aside -- I have no idea what & means to nasm -- it doesn't appear anywhere in the documentation I can see, so I'm suprised it doesn't give an error. But it looks like it treats it as an alias for [])

Oh, oh! You've discovered the secret syntax! "&" was added to Nasm (as an alias for "[]") per user request, a long time ago. It was never documented. Never removed, either. I'd stick with "[]". Being "undocumented", it might just disappear. Note that the meaning is almost "opposite" from what it means to gdb!

Might try "-F dwarf" instead of "-F stabs". It's supposed to be the "native" debugging info format used by gdb. (never noticed much difference, myself)

Best,

Frank

http://www.nasm.us