# what's meaning of 'leaq label(register) ,register' in asm

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

i am reading the asm code below,but i do not know what's the meaning of 
statement

`finish(%rip)`

the part of  asm below:

```
    /* compute abs address of label finish */
    leaq  finish(%rip), %rcx
    /* save address of finish as return-address for context-function */
    /* will be entered after context-function returns */
    movq  %rcx, 0x40(%rax)

    ret /* return pointer to context-data */

finish:
    /* exit code is zero */
    xorq  %rdi, %rdi
    /* exit application */
    call  _exit@PLT
    hlt
```

i have search many answer ,the most likely answer is below:

```
lea eax, msg
```

makes no sense -- the source is the label (address) msg, which is a (link time) constant and is not in memory anywhere.
[answer from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11461671/6229548)

## question:

i still do not know what's meaning of `finish(%rip)`.
i know `finish` is label , `rip` is register ,but what's meaning of  `finish(%rip)`?

Comment: It's just a syntax for getting the address of `finish` in a rip-relative position independent way. See also the [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMemory.html).

Comment: RIP-relative is a special case: instead of adding the absolute address of the symbol with the register like in `lea foo(%rax), %rdi`, `foo(%rip)` addresses `foo` relative to RIP.

Comment: `lea eax, msg` is Intel syntax, not AT&T.  You can tell because the destination is on the left, and the register has no `%`.  It's an inefficient choice vs. `mov $msg, %eax`, though; only ever use LEA for static addresses if you're using RIP-relative.